# jQuery Add Array Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json given below

```
0 : {car_rental_id: "6007", sharing_schedule: "9:00 AM", booked_cars: '1', woo_order_id: "6421", woo_status: "on-hold" }
1 : {car_rental_id: "6007", sharing_schedule: "9:00 AM", booked_cars: '3', woo_order_id: "6424", woo_status: "pending" }
2 : {car_rental_id: "6007", sharing_schedule: "10:00 AM", booked_cars: '5', woo_order_id: "6427", woo_status: "pending"}
```

The goal here is to get the total number of `booked_cars` on a time. So according to this json. I should get

4 bookings for 9:00 AM and 5 bookings for 10:00 AM.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I think the issue is that you are assigning `=` the value, so it always replaces, you could try creating the object you need using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: `window.confirmedBookings` has a `length` property, so it's an Array, yes?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes

Answer (score 2):

You could change it to something like that.

```
var values = window.confirmedBookings.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    if(!prev[current.sharing_schedule]) prev[current.sharing_schedule] = 0;
    prev[current.sharing_schedule] += Number(current.booked_cars);
    return prev;
}, {})
```

@edit: updated an answer to fit a question.

Comment: Its not necessary that I use an object, we can use an array too. I just need to make it in the given order

Comment: Alright, now it makes more sense. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var test = [{
  car_rental_id: "6007",
  sharing_schedule: "9:00 AM",
  woo_order_id: "6421",
  woo_status: "on-hold",
  booked_cars: '1'
}, {
  car_rental_id: "6007",
  sharing_schedule: "9:00 AM",
  woo_order_id: "6424",
  woo_status: "pending",
  booked_cars: '3'
}, {
  car_rental_id: "6007",
  sharing_schedule: "10:00 AM",
  woo_order_id: "6427",
  woo_status: "pending",
  booked_cars: '5'
}];

var carsBookedByTime = test.reduce(function(collection, element){
  var bookedCars = parseInt(element.booked_cars);
  //initialize total in the collection if it does not exist
  if (!collection[element.sharing_schedule]) collection[element.sharing_schedule] = 0;
  
  collection[element.sharing_schedule] += bookedCars;

return collection;
}, {});

console.log(carsBookedByTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking for :

```
window.totalBooked = {};
$.each(window.confirmedBookings, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.booked_cars);
window.totalBooked[value.sharing_schedule] = (window.totalBooked[value.sharing_schedule] || 0) + +value.booked_cars;
});
```

or, slightly simpler :

```
window.totalBooked = window.confirmedBookings.reduce(function(obj, value) {
    obj[value.sharing_schedule] = (obj[value.sharing_schedule] || 0) + +value.booked_cars;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ffqye6cp/)**

Comment: Check the question again mate